# Xamarin forms: How to parse string data from notification in ios platform?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Following is my notification body:

```
{
 "to" : "My device FCM Token",
 "notification" : 
 {
     "body" : "Hi....",
     "title": "Test"  
 },
 "data" : 
 {
    "commentMessageType": "support",
    "requestData":
       {
            "request": {
                "itemId": 3462,
                "itemTitle": "Request for books",
                "itemDescription": "Request for books",
            },
            "category": "Books",
            "companyId": 74366,
            "companyName": "manish thomas-Furniture Mart hub",
            "location": {
                "locationId": 0,
                "locationName": null,
                "blogCollectionId": 0,
                "fileUrl": null
            },
            "lockedLocation": null,
            "itemRequesterName": "Albee "
        }
    }
}
```

I can read the `requestData` like below in ios platform:

```
var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestList>(userInfo[new NSString("requestData")] as NSString);
```

But when I try to read the `commentMessageType` like below I am getting `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 1, position 1.`.

```
var commentType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(userInfo[new NSString("commentMessageType")] as NSString);
```

I tried another way like below, but I got `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
NSDictionary data = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("data")) as NSDictionary;
string commentType = Convert.ToString(data[new NSString("commentMessageType")] as NSString);
```

What is the exact way to parse a string data from notification?

Comment: You don’t need to deserialize it because it’s just a string

Comment: Xamarin.iOS can “implicitly“ convert NSString to string. Try `string commentType = userInfo[new NSString("commentMessageType")] as NSString;`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve please add it as your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS can “implicitly“ convert NSString to string.

Try:

```cs
string commentType = userInfo[new NSString("commentMessageType")] as NSString;
```